# Unmet dependencies in base packages - jenkins dockerfile

Tags: apt, docker

Below is the dockerfile:

```
FROM jenkins:2.60.3

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

USER root
ARG DOCKER_GID=497

RUN groupadd -g ${DOCKER_GID:-497} docker

ARG DOCKER_ENGINE=1.10.2
ARG DOCKER_COMPOSE=1.6.2

# Install base packages for docker, docker-compose & ansible
RUN apt-get update -y && \
    apt-get install apt-transport-https curl python-dev python-setuptools gcc make libssl-dev -y && \
    easy_install pip

# Install docker engine
RUN apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://p80.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 --recv-keys 58118E89F3A912897C070ADBF76221572C52609D && \
    echo "deb https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo ubuntu-trusty main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list && \
    apt-get update -y && \
    apt-get purge lxc-docker* -y && \
    apt-get install docker-engine=${DOCKER_ENGINE:-1.10.2}-0~trusty -y && \
    usermod -aG docker jenkins && \
    usermod -aG users jenkins

# Install docker compose
RUN pip install docker-compose==${DOCKER_COMPOSE:-1.6.2} && \
    pip install ansible boto boto3

# Change to jenkins user
USER jenkins

# Add jenkins plugin
COPY plugins.txt /usr/share/jenkins/plugins.txt
RUN /usr/local/bin/plugins.sh /usr/share/jenkins/plugins.txt
```

---

give below error:

```
Step 9/14 : RUN apt-get update -y &&     apt-get install apt-transport-https curl python-dev python-setuptools gcc make libssl-dev -y &&     easy_install pip
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 297087071292
Step 10/14 : RUN apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://p80.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 --recv-keys 58118E89F3A912897C070ADBF76221572C52609D &&     echo "deb https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo ubuntu-trusty main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list &&     apt-get update -y &&     apt-get purge lxc-docker* -y &&     apt-get install docker-engine=${DOCKER_ENGINE:-1.10.2}-0~trusty -y &&     usermod -aG docker jenkins &&     usermod -aG users jenkins
 ---> Running in 10daeb70c472
Warning: apt-key output should not be parsed (stdout is not a terminal)
Executing: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.ls7Ck5WuuS/gpg.1.sh --keyserver hkp://p80.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 --recv-keys 58118E89F3A912897C070ADBF76221572C52609D
gpg: key F76221572C52609D: public key "Docker Release Tool (releasedocker) <docker@docker.com>" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1
deb https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo ubuntu-trusty main
Get:1 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates InRelease [94.3 kB]
Ign:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch InRelease
Get:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates InRelease [91.0 kB]
Hit:4 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch Release
Get:5 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main amd64 Packages [500 kB]
Get:6 https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo ubuntu-trusty InRelease [48.7 kB]
Get:8 https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo ubuntu-trusty/main amd64 Packages [7033 B]
Fetched 741 kB in 1s (606 kB/s)
Reading package lists...
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
Package 'lxc-docker' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'lxc-docker-virtual-package' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 57 not upgraded.
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 docker-engine : Depends: libsystemd-journal0 (>= 201) but it is not installable
                 Recommends: aufs-tools but it is not going to be installed
                 Recommends: cgroupfs-mount but it is not going to be installed or
                             cgroup-lite but it is not installable
                 Recommends: apparmor but it is not going to be installed
                 Recommends: yubico-piv-tool (>= 1.1.0~) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
ERROR: Service 'jenkins' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://p80.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 --recv-keys 58118E89F3A912897C070ADBF76221572C52609D &&     echo "deb https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo ubuntu-trusty main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list &&     apt-get update -y &&     apt-get purge lxc-docker* -y &&     apt-get install docker-engine=${DOCKER_ENGINE:-1.10.2}-0~trusty -y &&     usermod -aG docker jenkins &&     usermod -aG users jenkins' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

---

Below instructions are causing this error:

```
  apt-get install docker-engine=${DOCKER_ENGINE:-1.10.2}-0~trusty -y
  deb https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo ubuntu-trusty main
```

---

1) How to resolve these unmet dependencies?

2) Which is the recommended version of Jenkins? Currently using base  image `2.60.3`

Comment: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases says that "Trusty" was "End of Standard Support" in April of 2019

Comment: Note also the deprecation notice at https://hub.docker.com/_/jenkins saying "This image has been deprecated in favor of the jenkins/jenkins:lts image provided and maintained by Jenkins Community as part of project's release process. The images found here will receive no further updates after LTS 2.60.x. Please adjust your usage accordingly."

Comment: Why are you trying to install Docker Compose *inside* a container?

Comment: @StephenKitt because this Jenkins container, it creates test & release environment(docker containers)

Answer (score 1):

From the provided output, your specific issue is that the packages you want to install depend on `libsystemd-journal0`, and you have no configured repositories that provide that package.  It seems you have a mix of Debian and Ubuntu repositories inside that container and that is likely the source of your problem.

From what I can decipher, that Docker image you are using is not even Ubuntu, it is running on Debian Stretch, so you should not be installing the Ubuntu Docker repository inside that container.

Once you make a container using the Docker repository for Debian Stretch, it should build.

Your other problem is that you are trying to get Docker running inside Docker, which you will find has some of its own issues/limitations, but you will likely get to that once the container is built, and should probably be submitted as additional questions.

As for the recommended Jenkins Docker image, the link [from the image you are currently using](https://hub.docker.com/_/jenkins) brought me to [this image](https://hub.docker.com/r/jenkins/jenkins) which also looks to be running `openjdk-8` on Debian Stretch.

Comment: For your point:'. It seems you have a mix of Debian and Ubuntu repositories'... Can you suggest changes?

Comment: You are adding an Ubuntu repository to a Debian image, which should not be done.  Just add the proper Debian repository from the Docker documentation for best results.  Use `https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo debian-stretch  main` instead of the `ubuntu-trusty` repository.

Comment: What about `apt-get install docker-engine=${DOCKER_ENGINE:-1.10.2}-0~trusty -y` instruction?

Comment: That looks to be an Ubuntu Trusty package, as indicated by the `trusty` tag in the name.  You need to find the name of the [package from the Debian repositories, which I found as docker-engine_1.10.2-0~stretch_amd64.deb](https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo/pool/main/d/docker-engine/docker-engine_1.10.2-0~stretch_amd64.deb).  I am not sure about the `apt.dockerproject.org` repository as it does not appear to be currently maintained, you may want to use the official `download.docker.com` for packages.

Comment: Wrote a complete new version of dockerfile, but unable to install docker.....https://devops.stackexchange.com/q/9750/11527